# What does "all stand" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have to know what "all stand" means for a final test tomorrow. I've looked all over Google, with not a trace of what it may mean. It's a term used by sailors, that's the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: Context, please? Because I can construct all sorts of sentences where the words "all" and "stand" happen to end up next to each other. And there's also "All stand for the national anthem."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From *[The Glossary of Nautical Terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_nautical_terms)*:

> *All standing*
>
> Bringing a person or thing up short, that is an unforeseen and sudden
>   stop.
>
> *Wikipedia*

Comment: Haha, I posted the same thing at the same time as you. I'll take mine down.

Comment: No harm, no foul, @JaredKauffman.